# can we listen to incoming messages in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a registration form that sends a 5 digit number to confirm mobile phone, and the site gets the digits in next form, I want to take it one step further and if the user is registering on his phone listen on messages and auto-fill the input.
so is it possible to do that? listening to incoming messages from a browser?
if we can, how?
thanks.

Comment: You question is a little unclear, but is sounds like you want to know when the user is typing the code/ has finished typing the code?

Comment: no, i want to listen and when a message with the name of my sites is received on user's mobile, then grab the code and auto-fill the input and auto submit so that user doesn't have to go to messages and grab the number and fill the input and then submit it, like WhatsApp

Comment: No, it is not possible to intercept/access SMS messages from the browser. If you don't want your user to have to c&p, use a hyperlink (in addition to the numeric code).

Comment: As Bergi has stated, no that's not possible. Even then, you'd be sending them the code, you already have it the code, why would you need to intercept it? That's besides the point you want the user to input the code other wise you don't really have 2FA, you just have a pointless step in your authentication process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2way communication with the server using WebSockets. One of the easiest ways to use WebSocket is with https://socket.io/

You create socket server with nodejs, connect with socekt.io client from browser and server can push any event to the browser just like a browser can push any event back to the server.

WebSocket communication is considered as real time while it does not create new HTTP handshake stuff.

**If you want to read user's SMS. You have to have permission to do so**. You can't read SMS from web application running in browser. Only way to work around i can think is this pattern:

1. your user has your native application which can read sms and runs in a background
2. your app reads sms and sends notification to your websocket server about it
3. your browser receives confirmation from the same WebSocket about message received

Comment: Lukas I suggest you read the comments under the question, especially _i want to listen and when a message with the name of my sites is received on user's mobile, then grab the code and auto-fill the input_ WebSockets are great but they can't intercept SMS messages.

Comment: sockets are great and I'm using it to check the inputs but still, the user needs to fill that input

Comment: If you follow all 3 steps, you will have details about SMS and you can fill up the form using some JS on client side

Comment: Thanks for respond,